# How to stop form input with `disabled` attribute from sending?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Form inputs with the `disabled` attribute are not suppose to send by the client.

But for some reason both `#id_of_first_div` and `#id_of_second_div` are sending despite toggling of the radio button between `#challenge_category_one-shot` and `#challenge_category_ongoing`.

### _form

```
<%= form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :action %>
  <% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>
    <%= label(c, c) %>:
    <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher", checked: (c=='One-Shot')) %>
  <% end %>

  <div id='id_of_first_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :deadline %>
  </div>

  <div id='id_of_second_div'>
    <%= f.date_select :date_started %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<script>
  $(function(){
     $('#id_of_second_div').hide();
     $('#challenge_category_one-shot').click(function(){ 
        $('#id_of_first_div').show().attr('disabled', false); 
        $('#id_of_second_div').hide().attr('disabled', true); 
     });
     $('#challenge_category_ongoing').click(function(){
       $('#id_of_first_div').hide().attr('disabled', true); 
       $('#id_of_second_div').show().attr('disabled', false);
     });
  });
</script>
```

### Radio Button HTML

```
<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="One-Shot" checked="checked" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_one-shot" />

<input class="date-format-switcher" type="radio" value="Ongoing" name="challenge[category]" id="challenge_category_ongoing" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Form inputs with the disabled attribute are not suppose to send by the client." <= **this is not correct.**

"disabled" does **NOT** mean "do not send to the server". It means "do not allow user to interact with".

If you want the value not to be sent back to the server, then you'll need to remove the element from the tree.